# GCloud Vision API's NewImageAnnotatorClient throwing Permission Denied using option.WithCredentialsFile

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-vision, google-product-search

I have two GCP projects, projectA for kubernetes resources and projectB for product-search-api and spanner database. I created a service account in projectB with required permissions and mount its `credentials.json` to the service in projectA as `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var **and it works well**.

But because of this there are some other permissions issue for the service using features in projectA for eg. stackdriver monitoring etc. I could grant these permissions to the service account I created but I then found a `ClientOption - withCredentialsFile`.

I planned to use this option without modifying `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var in the service i.e. keep using projectA credentials. So, I passed it to spanner client like below and it works well

```
client, err := spanner.NewClientWithConfig(context, dbn, spanner.ClientConfig{
        SessionPoolConfig: spanner.SessionPoolConfig{
            MaxIdle: 100,
        },
    }, option.WithCredentialsFile(cfg.CredsPathtoProjectB))
```

But when I pass it to `vision.NewImageAnnotatorClient` to make request to ProductSearchAPI, I get `Permission Denied`.

```
c, err := vision.NewImageAnnotatorClient(context, option.WithCredentialsFile(cfg.CredsPathtoProjectB))
ictx := &pb.ImageContext{
    ProductSearchParams: &pb.ProductSearchParams{
        ProductSet:        fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s/locations/%s/productSets/%s", cfg.ProjectID, cfg.ProjectLocation, cfg.ProductSetID),
        ProductCategories: []string{cfg.ProductCategory},
        Filter:            filter,
    },
}
response, err := c.AnnotateImage(ctx, &pb.AnnotateImageRequest{
    Image:        img,
    ImageContext: ictx,
    Features:     []*pb.Feature{{Type: visionpb.Feature_PRODUCT_SEARCH, 
    MaxResults: int32(maxItems)}},
})
------------------------
<OUTPUT>
"response:":"error:{code:7 message:\"Permission denied.\"}"
```

I could use same credentials to request product search API when overwriting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. Am I making any mistake?

Comment: Can you share more details regarding your issue? Which doc you have followed? What are the roles and permission you have added in your service account?

Comment: Because the google-product-search API requires owner permissions of the project, service account has owner permissions of projectB.

Comment: Let me add more details.

Comment: Yes please add more details and also which doc are you following to configure cross-project service accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Owner's permission on the service account. However, if the product search resources are in projectB, then you have to call Vision API with a service account from projectB.